# create a class library for a sharepoint project

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to put my sharepoint code in an external library. Once I reference the dll in my project and when I do a deployment, I get an error saying that Could not load file or assembly. 
Can anyone tell me what should I do when creating my class library? what references do I have to include?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10):

You should both sign your class library and include it into your package. in order to include a library into a package go to package designer and click Advanced then add your library to the package from there via **Add Custom Assembly**.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, sharepoint requires external assemblies be signed and loaded from the GAC. Are you installing your DLL into the GAC and is it signed?

Answer (score 1):

You can click on "advance" on the package designer and add your external dll, assuming you are using sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

Go to packages and add the External DLL's to the GAC